# Work with vba excel 2010 32 bit and excel 2016 64 bit clipboard

Tags: vba, excel, 32bit-64bit

Today im using this code to copy a file to clipboard with excel 2010 (32 bit).
Im trying to get this to work with office 2016 (64 bit), but everytime the function is used excel crashes.

Is it possible to get this code to work with both excel 2016 (64 bit) and office 2010 (32 bit)?

```
Option Explicit

' Required data structures
Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

' Clipboard Manager Functions
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long

' Other required Win32 APIs
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DragQueryFile Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "DragQueryFileA" (ByVal hDrop As Long, ByVal UINT As Long, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal ch As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DragQueryPoint Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal hDrop As Long, lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalFree Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMem Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

' Predefined Clipboard Formats
Private Const CF_TEXT = 1
Private Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Private Const CF_METAFILEPICT = 3
Private Const CF_SYLK = 4
Private Const CF_DIF = 5
Private Const CF_TIFF = 6
Private Const CF_OEMTEXT = 7
Private Const CF_DIB = 8
Private Const CF_PALETTE = 9
Private Const CF_PENDATA = 10
Private Const CF_RIFF = 11
Private Const CF_WAVE = 12
Private Const CF_UNICODETEXT = 13
Private Const CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14
Private Const CF_HDROP = 15
Private Const CF_LOCALE = 16
Private Const CF_MAX = 17

' New shell-oriented clipboard formats
Private Const CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST As String = "Shell IDList Array"
Private Const CFSTR_SHELLIDLISTOFFSET As String = "Shell Object Offsets"
Private Const CFSTR_NETRESOURCES As String = "Net Resource"
Private Const CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR As String = "FileGroupDescriptor"
Private Const CFSTR_FILECONTENTS As String = "FileContents"
Private Const CFSTR_FILENAME As String = "FileName"
Private Const CFSTR_PRINTERGROUP As String = "PrinterFriendlyName"
Private Const CFSTR_FILENAMEMAP As String = "FileNameMap"

' Global Memory Flags
Private Const GMEM_FIXED = &H0
Private Const GMEM_MOVEABLE = &H2
Private Const GMEM_NOCOMPACT = &H10
Private Const GMEM_NODISCARD = &H20
Private Const GMEM_ZEROINIT = &H40
Private Const GMEM_MODIFY = &H80
Private Const GMEM_DISCARDABLE = &H100
Private Const GMEM_NOT_BANKED = &H1000
Private Const GMEM_SHARE = &H2000
Private Const GMEM_DDESHARE = &H2000
Private Const GMEM_NOTIFY = &H4000
Private Const GMEM_LOWER = GMEM_NOT_BANKED
Private Const GMEM_VALID_FLAGS = &H7F72
Private Const GMEM_INVALID_HANDLE = &H8000
Private Const GHND = (GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_ZEROINIT)
Private Const GPTR = (GMEM_FIXED Or GMEM_ZEROINIT)

Private Type DROPFILES
    pFiles As Long
    pt As POINTAPI
    fNC As Long
    fWide As Long
End Type
Public Function ClipboardCopySingleFile(File As String) As Boolean

Dim Files(0) As String
Files(0) = File
ClipboardCopyFiles Files()

End Function
Public Function ClipboardCopyFiles(Files() As String) As Boolean

Dim data As String
Dim df As DROPFILES
Dim hGlobal As Long
Dim lpGlobal As Long
Dim I As Long

' Open and clear existing crud off clipboard.
If OpenClipboard(0&) Then
    Call EmptyClipboard

    ' Build double-null terminated list of files.
    For I = LBound(Files) To UBound(Files)
        data = data & Files(I) & vbNullChar
    Next
    data = data & vbNullChar

    ' Allocate and get pointer to global memory,
    ' then copy file list to it.
    hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GHND, Len(df) + Len(data))
    If hGlobal Then
        lpGlobal = GlobalLock(hGlobal)

        ' Build DROPFILES structure in global memory.
        df.pFiles = Len(df)
        Call CopyMem(ByVal lpGlobal, df, Len(df))
        Call CopyMem(ByVal (lpGlobal + Len(df)), ByVal data, Len(data))
        Call GlobalUnlock(hGlobal)

        ' Copy data to clipboard, and return success.
        If SetClipboardData(CF_HDROP, hGlobal) Then
            ClipboardCopyFiles = True
        End If
    End If

    ' Clean up
    Call CloseClipboard
End If

End Function
Public Function ClipboardPasteFiles(Files() As String) As Long

Dim hDrop As Long
Dim nFiles As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim desc As String
Dim filename As String
Dim pt As POINTAPI
Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

' Insure desired format is there, and open clipboard.
If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_HDROP) Then
    If OpenClipboard(0&) Then

        ' Get handle to Dropped Filelist data, and number of files.
        hDrop = GetClipboardData(CF_HDROP)
        nFiles = DragQueryFile(hDrop, -1&, "", 0)

        ' Allocate space for return and working variables.
        ReDim Files(0 To nFiles - 1) As String
        filename = Space(MAX_PATH)

        ' Retrieve each filename in Dropped Filelist.
        For I = 0 To nFiles - 1
            Call DragQueryFile(hDrop, I, filename, Len(filename))
            Files(I) = TrimNull(filename)
        Next

        ' Clean up
        Call CloseClipboard
    End If

    ' Assign return value equal to number of files dropped.
    ClipboardPasteFiles = nFiles
End If

End Function
Private Function TrimNull(ByVal sTmp As String) As String

Dim nNul As Long

' Truncate input sTmpg at first Null.
' If no Nulls, perform ordinary Trim.

nNul = InStr(sTmp, vbNullChar)
Select Case nNul
    Case Is > 1
    TrimNull = Left(sTmp, nNul - 1)
    Case 1
    TrimNull = ""
    Case 0
    TrimNull = Trim(sTmp)
End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the need of compile directives?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264731.aspx

I have used before, for similar problems, something like the example below:

```
#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiGetComputerName Lib "kernel32" Alias _
"GetComputerNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function apiGetComputerName Lib "kernel32" Alias _
"GetComputerNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
#End If
```

Comment: Sorry, My skill set isnt that good. Not always fully aware of what everything is doing in this advanced functions and how things work. So im not sure how this will help me. Sorry about that, but greatful for all help i get.